# meaning of "ls -la" color

Tags: ls

I'm using Ubuntu12.04 and I've created two directory symbolic links.
By using `ls -la`, console shows source directory with light blue and target directory with blue.

But only one of them target directory background is green.
The permission of two directories are same and user and group are also same.
What is difference between two of them? What meaning have green background with `ls -la --color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have write permissions even if the file is not yours and it's sticky:

[image]

Please, don't confuse with the SUID, which take precedence.

The `dircolors -p` will print you the complete database in which we find:

```
[...]
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
[...]
```

Comment: You can also look in these files for the color settings: `/etc/DIR_COLORS*`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I linked the directory from dropbox directory. Maybe that is the reason.